# Android Database - Foreign Key

Tags: android, database, foreign-keys

Can someone clarify foreign keys in the Android database environment?
I have successfully established the databases with all the bells and whistles.

But I can't find working information on how to connect two databases with foreign keys?

Comment: did you mean two **tables** with foreign keys?  You can't really link databases together with foreign keys, since in SQLite a database is simply a file.

Answer (score 2):

There is no reason to link databases, so I assume you mean tables. You can easily link tables by referring an id in one table to another using the `references row(table)` statement.

My database has students in one table and grades in another. Each grade
refers to the student by id like this:

Table Students:

```
studentname  text  
studentemail text  
studentid integer primary key autoincrements
```

Table Grades:

```
grade integer  
student integer references studentid(Students)
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [SQLite documentation on the topic Foreign Key](http://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html).